# Pandas: Counting empty values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing some info about purchases. It includes columns like "purchaseID", "purchaseDate", and "purchaseAmount". I want to know the number of missing values in each column, and different columns contain different types of datatypes like strings, numeric, booleans, etc. I tried something like this:

```
import json
import pandas

# the variable 'data' is my pandas data frame which was read from a json
with open('purchases.json') as f:
    data = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(line) for line in f)

print(data.isnull().sum())
print(data.isna().sum())
```

However, both isnull and isna are showing that there are no null values in any columns, which is not the case.

When I tried something like this:

```
for col in data.columns: 
    print((data[col].values == '').sum())
```

it works for some columns but not for columns that contain numeric or boolean data. Is there a way for me to find the empty values in all the columns?

Thanks!

Example printout using print of couple lines of data

```
purchaseID purchaseDate purchaseAmount merchantName
1234       2019-01-01   500.0          Walmart
2345       2019-01-03
           2019-01-02   25.1           BP
```

Comment: you need to convert your spaces into true `NaN` or pandas null values, try `df.replace('', np.nan)` then try your code above.

Comment: I event tried that before, and it is still showing 0 empty values for all columns

Comment: you need to show a sample of your data, it works for me but no on here can reproduce your error without a sample dataset.

Comment: @Datanovice just added a sample to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: `df.replace(' ', np.nan)` works for me, also using your code above `df.isnull().sum()` works for me and shows me 3 missing values.

Comment: Yea that is weird, seems like it should work but still not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `pd.read_json`. The problem could be your data frame with one row being the json file.

```
data = pd.read_json(r'purchases.json')
print(data.isnull().sum())
print(data.isna().sum().sum())
```